# What should I do with nuggets?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I visited the quarry and acquired some silver & gold nuggets. I'd like to sell them, but only if there's nothing more useful I can do with them. I also am not sure where to sell them since the Nooklings won't take them.

What should I do with my nuggets?

Comment: You can normally sell things from your crafting inventory by tapping them and then either clicking "List for Sale" to add them to your market box or "Sell" to sell directly.  I haven't encountered nuggets to know whether they have this option though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The five items you break out of rocks at the quarry (or 'minerals', as the game calls them) are not added to your inventory; they are simply a measure of the relative success of your quarry visit, and the resulting payout.

The minerals you can find in rocks are as follows:

- Various gemstones: Good
- Silver nuggets: Better
- Gold nuggets: Best

How well you did determines how much of the featured item you collect after your visit, whether that's themed essence (like Cool, Cute, Modern, Harmonious, etc.), a custom crafting material (such as the Mario event mushrooms, the holiday candy canes, the various gyroidites, etc.), or bells. Note that you will *also* get bells even if bells were not the featured item at the quarry during that period; for that matter, you will generally get more bells for doing worse. This appears to be a sort of protection against bad luck so that the value of quarry visits remains relatively stable. Because of this, I try to avoid going to the quarry when the featured items are bells, since bad luck on a bells-only visit awards nothing extra.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. I went to the quarry and got a mix of 3 minerals, a gold nugget and a silver nugget. My final reward was 1,500 Bells and some essence per the time slots reward. However, I just went in again and I only got silver and gold nuggets. The total reward at the end was a measly 450 Bells. That makes it seem like minerals/gems are worth more than the nuggest, even though Lliod mentions the nuggets

Comment: Hmm. This is quite the contradiction. I found this page which seems to corroborate my original claims; it suggests that you'll get fewer bells if you earn more materials, and vice versa, but it repeats the claim that silver and gold correspond to a higher payout in general, although the presence or absence of a sparkling quarry icon may initially impact your reward levels, as well.  https://sirtaptap.com/2017/10/animal-crossing-pocket-camp-guide/#shovelstrike_quarry

Comment: I just went again and got 2 gold nuggets, one silver, and two rubies. I also had bells as the bonus reward for the time frame. My final reward was 4,200 bells.

Comment: Last time I mined I got 3 gold nuggets, 1 silver nugget, and 1 ruby and was doled out a measly 650 bells. I believe the bonus reward was some sort of essence.

Comment: Trying to rate payouts without listing both bell gain AND essence gain is like trying to determine which two-digit number is bigger by looking only at the ones column. We need the full payout to see what's going on here, especially as Lloid highlights crafting materials in his dialogue, but doesn't highlight bells. I just went on a non-shiny tour and collected two silver, two gold, and one sapphire; my payout was 700 bells and 8 natural essence.

Comment: Just went again during a shining sporty essence period. I got two silver and three gold, resulting in 9 sporty essence and 450 bells.